# Cast ObjectProxy to Object/Dictionary in ActionScript

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, dictionary, casting

How do I do this without doing a deep traversal?

I'm using as3corelib's JSON encoder, which encodes differently than expected `if ( describeType( o ).@name.toString() != "Object"`.

I'm calling using HttpService to load some data, and it returns it in as a mx.utils::ObjectProxy object, whose .object attribute is protected.

I've tried casting using `Object(o)` and `o as Object`, but those don't change the markers that `describeType` looks for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the variable "makeObjectsBindable" of HTTP service is set to "true".
Turn it to false, and you should have an object instead of an objectProxy